# Flash projects with flash player above 7 don't work since CS5

Tags: flash

I have somewhat simple problem with my Flash projects. I've installed Flash CS5, created new project (AS2), made a simple button which on(release) is gotoAndPlay(2), published and... It doesn't work! After some research I noticed that none action scipt works when i choose to publish my project with flash player 8,9,10. This is really strange for me.I don't want to stick with FP7. Does anybody know why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Flash Players above 7 DO NOT support Actionscript 2 which is really strange for me. I had to change code to AS3 and it works fine now.